# JBoss EAP 6.4 static module referencing EJB jar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I'm porting a custom login module from JBoss 5.1 to JBoss EAP 6.4. I've turned it into a static module, but now I have the problem the lookup fails. I get this error:

```
18:25:02,770 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: eu/somecompany/service/auth/AuthenticationService
```

Which is not strange as this class lives in jar inside an ear deployed on JBoss.

So I want to add a dependency to the module.xml:

```
<module name="deployment.my-ear.ear.mycompany-service.jar"/>
```

But then i get this error:

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: deployment.my-ear.ear.mycompany-service.jar:main
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1050) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
```

It can't be found. So my question is. How do I let my custom login module talk to my EJB service layer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a dependency on your EJB application to the login module. This can be done in a MANIFEST.MF file or a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file.